# Optimal key hashes in redis

Tags: redis

I've been reading the article here by on redis's website about using `HSET` vs `SET` to create a much more optimised memory usage:
http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization

The problem I have is that my keys are much longer than this. They are of the form:
`u:<USER_ID that is 9-16 characters>`

Examples:

```
u:123456789
u:123456789abcdefg
```

Where is the most optimal place to split the key to use with `HSET`?

I had read [here](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs) that ideally you would have no more than 1000 items in each "sub-set". So in that case I would split by the last 3 characters resulting in a theoretically  maximum of 999 items in each set.

Unfortunately the user id's are not that predictable and I cannot guarantee a good spread. For example if I split at `HSET u:123456 789` I could not guarantee there would be all the other user id's that began with 123456 filling the set, meaning memory would not be that optimised.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** It seems you are misunderstanding the article. It is *not* about "using HSET vs SET". It is about saving memory when using the *aggregate* data types (hashes, sets, sorted sets etc.), not single strings.

In your case it does not make sense to use a hash instead of a string, since you want each key to map to a single string.

You *need* to have the whole user ID in your key if you want the guarantee that you won't have collisions (ie. two users mapping to the same key).

However you could shard the hash and have your users within multiple hashes.

For example user IDs beginning with 1-3 would go into the first hash, 4-6 into the second, 7-9 into the third etc. You could use a hash function for storing and retrieving the users from certain hashes.

If you make sure that your hashes:

1. contain up to a certain limit of entries (see `hash-max-ziplist-entries` setting) *and*,
2. contain only keys and values with sizes up to the `hash-max-zipmap-value` setting (`1024` by default)

then you get a memory saving because your hashes are stored in a much more memory-efficient way, using a data structure called [*ziplist*](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/ziplist.c).

Note: These relevant settings are in the `redis.conf` file.

Comment: In both the examples above they split the hash into two.

Comment: It's a simple mapping. Key to one value. e.g. `u:123456 = "Dean C"`

Comment: I think you are confusing the data types. Then using a hash instead is no good. Just use simple strings. These memory optimizations you read concern only aggregate data types, not single strings. Update my answer.

Comment: Agis: thanks for the response. I'm still not quite getting how the sharding would work. Could you please give an example using the user id's in my first post and HSET commands. I thought that I was effectively sharding by splitting the "key".

Comment: I don't think this example is applicable to your case. The `HSET` commands refers to *Hashes*, meaning multiple maps between keys and values. Your case though is simpler than this, you have a 1 to 1 mapping, so you *do not* need to use Hashes. A simple string is what you need, and that is what `SET` is for. The sharding referred to the case you needed Hashes.